# No cookies in redirect chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, adfs

I have a site that redirect to another site (from the server) and then that site sets a cookie that tells the target url before redirecting to the adfs for saml authentication. After it redirects back the cookie is gone and it will open in the base url instead of the one specified in the cookie.

Note that if I enter the url directly without the first redirect, there's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
The problem was that the url I gave the adfs to redirect back to was different than the one I redirected to and thus the cookie didn't pass threw urls